# Show results from mysql query with php 5

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive bgwhite clgray">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalize" width="20">
                No
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalize">
                idbarang
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalize">
                Kategori
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalize">
                Merk
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalize">
                Foto
              </th>
              <th class="text-center text-capitalize">
                Stok
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <?php
            $queryStok  = "SELECT SUM(stok) AS jumlahbarang FROM tabelstok WHERE idjenisusaha=1 GROUP BY idbarang";
            $resultStok = mysqli_query($link,$queryStok);
            $queryStok2 = "SELECT * FROM tabelbarang,tabelmerk WHERE tabelbarang.idmerk=tabelmerk.idmerk";
            $resultStok2= mysqli_query($link,$queryStok2);
            while ($datastok=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultStok,$resultStok2)) {
          ?>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center text-capitalize">
                <?php echo $datastok['merk'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center text-capitalize">
                No
              </td>
              <td class="text-center text-capitalize">
                No
              </td>
              <td class="text-center text-capitalize">
                No
              </td>
              <td class="text-center text-capitalize">
                No
              </td>
              <td class="text-center text-capitalize">
                <?php echo $datastok['jumlahbarang'];?>
              </td>

          </tbody>
          <?php  }  ?>
        </table>
```

How can I show the result of 2 tables with 2 queries, in A SINGLE loop.

Comment: your code should be added to your question rather then linked to.

Comment: You need to join the two queries, not do them separately. Is there a column that relates the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to show the result of two queries without writting two `while` loops, you should use `mysqli_multi_query()` function to execute multiple queries at once. Each statement should have a semicollon at the end (the last statement should not contain the semicollon). You can add as many queries as you want.

   ```
   $query  = "YOUR FIRST STATEMENT;";
   $query .= "YOUR SECOND STATEMENT";
   $result = mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);
   do {
       $result = mysqli_store_result($link);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
          // DO YOUR STUFF HERE WITH $row
       }
       mysqli_free_result($result);
   } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
   ```
2. If you want to merge the queries into one, then if there is a column which connects/associates both tables, then you should use `JOIN` when you build the query. Example:

   ```
   SELECT customers.id, customers.name FROM customers
   INNER JOIN details ON customers.id=details.user_id;
   ```

   This merges the elements from `details` table with elements from `customers` table, linked by a common value (the customers ids).

As you didn't show the structure of the database, and tables I can't show an example based on your code, just a general one.

Comment: He seems to want to intermix the results of the two queries. multi-query executes them sequentially, not combining them.

Comment: @Barmar seems to be true. Yes, multi-query executes them sequentially. I don't understand well this question, but I just edited my answer and added a bit about `JOIN`.